# Custom symfony2 form

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.0

I have three entities, fos_user, command and preference. The user can send himself an email containing a specific field from each entity, these fields can't be empty. So when the user decides to send the mail, he should update/fill these fields through a form before sending the email. The new values will only be sent through the email and won't be saved into the database.
How do I build this form with needed validators?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser :), I'm working on something like this:

```
$o = new \stdClass();
$o->name = null;
$o->command_name = null;
$o->like_it = null;

$form = $this->createFormBuilder....
```

We can even use a table instead of stdClass object.